# Decode json into .Net Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, session

I have created a custom provider for managing session states for my web application and I am using `json serialization and deserialization` for session data in the provider. From the provider, I get back the json string from session collection which I have to deserialize in my web application to get the concrete type. I don't want to change the getter implementation of session from `(T)Session["Key"]` to `json.deserialize<T>(Session["Key"])` in my web application.
So for overcoming this I have to convert the json string to the .Net object in the provider itself. One way to do this is to use `Json.Decode` method of `System.Web.Helpers` which converts the json string to the .Net object but this is not feasible as the provider will have dependency on System.web. Other possible way is to create an `Expando objec`t but this object can't be typecasted to concrete type just by using (T)(eobject) so this is also not feasible. What are the other ways which I can use to convert json string to .Net object in my provider.

Answer (score 0):

Newtonsoft Json.Net does not have dependency on System.Web, though I couldn't figure out why that was a blocker for you.

https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: json.deserialize<T>(string) is the method provided by Newtonsoft Json.Net. We have to pass the concrete type for deserialization which I don't want to do.

Comment: I See, It has not been a problem for me because I tend to keep my model objects separated from classes that have functionality and thus implement interfaces as they need to be faked or injected.

Comment: Yes that's a good thing. I am making changes in the existing enterprise application which is not developed in this way so looking for alternatives.